# Using variables in cx_Oracle.connect method

Tags: python-2.x, cx-oracle, configparser

I'm trying to read env.properties file to get the credentials to connect to Oracle DB using cx_Oracle.
Variables have correct values but I guess issue is with the way I'm using connect method.
Is there something wrong?

```
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('env.properties')

user = config.get('DatabaseSection', 'database.user')
pwd  =  config.get('DatabaseSection', 'database.password')
host = config.get('DatabaseSection', 'database.db_host')
port = config.get('DatabaseSection', 'database.db_port')
instance = config.get('DatabaseSection', 'database.db_instance')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user,pwd,host:port/instance)
cur = conn.cursor()
```

Comment: There's a whole, long cx_Oracle manual chapter on connecting at https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html

Comment: Yes, I referred to the same page and inline with connection string mentioned there like
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("hr", userpwd, "dbhost.example.com:1984/orclpdb1",
        encoding="UTF-8")
I used - 
conn = cx_Oracle.connect("OMS1OMS","OMS1OMS","ilrtvit470:1521/VITDB470") which works, but when I use it reading properties file it worked with dsn only, not like - conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user,pwd,host:port/instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed with below piece of code -

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, instance)
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=user, password=pwd, dsn=dsn_tns)
```

Comment: With that syntax, you used an old fashioned SID not an instance.  The latter is recommended for a number of reasons.  Check the cx_Oracle makedsn() doc for the syntax.